# Transparent Background Problems

Tags: transparency

I've been trying to create a candle light using a png image with transparent background but cant seem to get it to work.

1. I unwrapped the plane in edit mode (not sure what it does but someone suggested to do it)
2. All the nodes seem to be connected exactly the way to achieve what I want

Can someone please suggest what could be wrong please?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, https://pasteall.org/blend/5fc8a391edd4400dbaf122222a9d54a7 

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch the *Mix Shader* inputs and you're good:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help once again.